# Modify a Module's output from a theme

Tags: theming

I'm really pulling my hair out about this one and wonder if someone can help?

Is it possible to override a module's output from the theme's template.php file?
Basically, I wan't to modify the output of the Geolocation Module without updating the module output itself.

if so, how would I go about it?

thanks a lot

Dave

Answer (score 0):

Your question is somewhat vague, what specifically is the "output" you want to override?! Is it drupal `Field` output, a theme variable such as `$vars['geolocation-something-foo']` ... or something else?

There is likely a [preprocess or process Hook](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme/7) you can implement to slide in your changes. Or using [Devel Themer](http://drupal.org/project/devel_themer) you can probably override their template file with one of your own easily.

Something I did yesterday was override the implementing function of another module with a (local copy) of my own version of that function in a custom module -- tweaked to add HTML attributes and tags that I needed and were'nt provided by the raw HTML (non render array) output of the other module.

I followed the good example from this [Snugug: Overriding Drupal Theme Functions from your Module](http://snugug.com/musings/override-theme-functions-drupal-7-module) and used [HOOK_theme_registry_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_theme_registry_alter/7) using the following logic:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_registry_alter
 */
function mymodule__theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry) {
  $theme_registry['ORIGINALMODULE_function_name']['function'] = 'MYMODULE_function_name';
}
```

I think took the body from the original function, copied, tweaked and pasted it into `mymodule_function_name`. I believe this hook is callable from a theme as well ...